# Nested promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, promise.all

I am try to improve some performance problem and for this I am try to do followings

I have a **promises** array and I wanna return result of this after all promises at promises array are done.

by the way result of processA, processB and processC are important too because at // other logic I use them at somewhere.

```
const promiseResults = await Promise.all(promises);

 const [processA, processB, processC] = await Promise.all([
      asyncProcessForA(),
      asyncProcessForB(),
      asyncProcessForC(),
 ]);



 // other logic 
 // ....
 // ....


 return promiseResults;
```

So, I wanna add promiseResults inside promise.all like

```
const [promiseResults, processA, processB, processC] = await Promise.all([
      Promise.all(promises),
      asyncProcessForA(),
      asyncProcessForB(),
      asyncProcessForC(),
 ]);


 // other logic 
 // ....
 // ....


 return promiseResults;
```

So, Is my way is good or not and also using **nested promise.all** is a good way or not? Because I do some search for best practices for using nested **promise.all** but I could not find anything So, what do you offer ?

Comment: There is nothing really specifically wrong with this. If this structure makes sense for your application, go for it.

Comment: You can add the `Promise.all()` promise to your other array that you then `await`, but you will end up with the first entry in the resulting array will be an array itself so you will have a result like this: `[[v1, v2, v2], valueA, valueB, valueC]` which may not be the most convenient data structure to use.  But, if that's what you want, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Using a nested `Promise.all()` as shown in your second example:

```
const [promiseResults, processA, processB, processC] = await Promise.all([
      Promise.all(promises),
      asyncProcessForA(),
      asyncProcessForB(),
      asyncProcessForC(),
]);
```

Works just fine.  `Promise.all()` expects an array of promises.  Since `Promise.all()` returns a promise, it's perfectly fine to use its promise in another call to `Promise.all()`.  The one gotcha here is that your outer `Promise.all()` will resolve to an array that has an embedded array in it like this:

```
[[v1, v2, v3], valueA, valueB, valueC]
```

Where `[v1, v2, v3]` are the resolved results from the inner `Promise.all()` (as passed through to the outer Promise.all()`and`valueA, valueB, valueC`are the resolved results from the other promises passed to the outer`Promise.all()`.  So, as long as you're prepared for the results to be organized like this, you can certainly work it this way.

---

You could also flatten the results and do something like this:

```
const [processA, processB, processC, ...promiseResults] = await Promise.all([
      asyncProcessForA(),
      asyncProcessForB(),
      asyncProcessForC(),
      ...promiseResults
]);
```

This would then give you a single combined and flat array of results which you can then assign out of or access however you want.  So, it really just depends upon how you want the results organized.

Answer (score -2):

I haven’t  use such construction, but if you don’t like it, you can wrap your promise.all in another promise, so it won’t be nested promise all.

Comment: What do you mean by "*wrap your promise.all in another promise*"?